# Selection in expected linear time from a array with a large number of repeated numbers

Tags: algorithm

In the book *Introduction to Algorithms Third Edition*, author introduce a selection algorithm in expected linear time. But it base on a basic assumption, the elements are distinct. But if I have a array with a large number of repeated numbers, such as a extreme condition, all of the array's elements are equal, obviously, it degrade into a O(n^2) time complexity algorithms. Does a linear time selection algorithm exist in a array with a large number of repeated numbers?

Example:
I have a array:
{2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 3}

And I want to know the N-th maximum number.

Such as N = 3, the answer is 7.

This is the selection problem.

Comment: @maraca Sorry, I can't image how to implement the algorithm by your description. But I feel that your alorithm is different from my target. I post a example, maybe my description is unintelligible.

Comment: If you have an algorithm which finds the nth biggest element out of distinct numbers, then it will work also for non-distinct array, because you can eliminate all duplicates in O(n). E.g.put all values in a hash set (and write back to another array if needed). Btw. there is also garanteed O(n) algorithm https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kth-smallestlargest-element-unsorted-array-set-3-worst-case-linear-time/?ref=lbp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop a [Dutch national flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem) three-way partition in there and adjust the logic concerning which subarray to recurse on, then you get an O(n) expected time algorithm.

This also works for median of medians.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented this algorithms with a similar way. This is useful.